# How to parse and split strings?

Tags: java

Can I get the number after the comma and put into a variable, and only two before the comma and put into another variable on Android?

I'm trying to do something like that...

I have the number 12,3456789
I want to get "12" and put into a variable A.
Then I want to get "34" and put into a variable B, there is a way to do that?

Comment: So you want all the numbers in the left of comma and only 2 to the right of comma?

Comment: Yes, only two to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        String all="12,3456789";
        String[] temp=all.split(",");
        String a=temp[0]; //12
        String b=temp[1]; //3456789
```

**Edit:**

if you want to get 2 no's after **,** than use `b.substring(0, 2)`

like :

```
  String c=b.substring(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny stuff:

```
double x = 12,3456789
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>;

while( x != 0) {

    int y = x; // 12
    values.add(y);

    x = (x - y) * 100; // 34,56789

}
```

To save it to an array you have to know how many digits x has to know how much elements you have to put in. I don't know a proper way right know so I'm using a Collection here.

Answer (score 0):

What Tarsem presented is ok, but you can also parse that String as a double and later [do](http://ideone.com/srEcbp) with it what you want:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String s = "12.3456789";
        double d = new Double(s);
        int a = (int) d;
        int b = (int) ((d - a) * 100);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12
34
```